# How to make this type of canvas with image in flutter?

Tags: flutter

[image]

how to create this type of design?

we can try but not create this type of.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved dynamically by [flutter_staggered_grid_view](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view).

```
GridView.custom(
  gridDelegate: SliverQuiltedGridDelegate(
    crossAxisCount: 4,
    mainAxisSpacing: 4,
    crossAxisSpacing: 4,
    repeatPattern: QuiltedGridRepeatPattern.inverted,
    pattern: [
      QuiltedGridTile(2, 2),
      QuiltedGridTile(1, 1),
      QuiltedGridTile(1, 1),
      QuiltedGridTile(1, 2),
    ],
  ),
  childrenDelegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
    (context, index) => ImageWidgetHere() // <-- your image 
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `flutter_staggered_grid_view`

```
import 'package:flutter_staggered_grid_view/flutter_staggered_grid_view.dart';


 StaggeredGrid.count(
      crossAxisCount: 4,
      mainAxisSpacing: 4,
      crossAxisSpacing: 4,
      children: const [
        StaggeredGridTile.count(
          crossAxisCellCount: 2,
          mainAxisCellCount: 2,
          child: Tile(index: 0),
        ),
        StaggeredGridTile.count(
          crossAxisCellCount: 2,
          mainAxisCellCount: 1,
          child: Tile(index: 1),
        ),
        StaggeredGridTile.count(
          crossAxisCellCount: 1,
          mainAxisCellCount: 1,
          child: Tile(index: 2),
        ),
        StaggeredGridTile.count(
          crossAxisCellCount: 1,
          mainAxisCellCount: 1,
          child: Tile(index: 3),
        ),
        StaggeredGridTile.count(
          crossAxisCellCount: 4,
          mainAxisCellCount: 2,
          child: Tile(index: 4),
        ),
      ],
    );
```

[image]